# What is the difference between the way that mono generates a web service proxy and the way visual studio does?

Tags: soap, mono

What is the difference between the way that mono generates a web service proxy and the way visual studio does?

By this I mean that in the mono world, you pop a terminal and type in:
    wsdl http://whateverlalala.com?wsdl

Whereas in the visual studio world you pop open a command prompt and type in:
    svcutil.exe http://whateverlalala.com?wsdl

In mono, the generated .cs file looks significantly different than the one that svcutil creates, and svcutil also makes a .config file that mono's tool doesn't. I'm not sure why these are so different, or what the significance of that is.

Answer (score 0):

In Mono, you appear to be using the tool for legacy ASMX service technology. Svcutil is for the current WCF service technology.

Have you tried to use svcutil in Mono? I don't do any Mono development, so I don't know whether it's available.

Comment: In mono, you're supposed to use a tool that's just called wsdl to generate the proxy, but it does it differently, which is why I asked my question.

Comment: In a Visual Studio installation, the tool named wsdl.exe is part of the legacy ASMX web service technology. I strongly suspect that the WSDL.EXE tool you're using is the Mono version of the same legacy tool.

Comment: Oh hey, you're correct. The mono project needs to update their documentation.

Comment: Yes, svcutil does seem to exist in the mono world. There's also a wsdl2, in addition to wsdl. They're all in /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/. Oddly enough, wsdl seems to support a higher version of the mono framework than wsdl2 does. I'm still not 100% clear on what the differences between all of these tools are.

Comment: I'm not sure what wsdl2 is, but I suggest not using it. Just use svcutil.

Comment: I checked with the mono people and apparently wsdl is the current tool. wsdl2 and svcutil are older versions of the same thing. BECAUSE THAT'S SO INTUITIVE AND WELL DOCUMENTED.

Comment: No, svcutil is not the "old version". Try svcutil in mono and see if it looks like the proxy generated by "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio. In fact, post the first few lines of "svcutil /?" and "wsdl /?"

Comment: According to the people that make mono, svcutil is the "old version" in the mono world. That might not be the case in Visual Studio.

Comment: This seems unlikely. Try the svcutil and see how it compares to the proxy format you were expecting.

Comment: I didn't really have any expectations. I just wanted to know why they were different.